# ActiveExplorer.ActiveInlineResponse slows down Outlook add-in application

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have an add-in that is usualy enabled for newly created emails. The task is to enable it for Reply/ReplyAll/Forward inline windows.

For a new email I use the `Inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem` but for inline explorer windows i have to use `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().ActiveInlineResponse as Outlook.MailItem` to get the mailitem object.

Everything is working fine when I use the `Inspector` but when I use the `ActiveInlineResponse` really slows down my application processing. At some point outlook does not respond at all.

In application I programmatically add attachments, write email header properties, change subject, body etc...

Can anyone explain me why is this happening and how can I fix it? I google it for 1 day now but with no success.

**EDIT:**
This is the method I use to get current mailitem.

```
        private MailItem GetMailItem()
    {
        Outlook.Application application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;

        if (application != null)
        {
            var windowType = application.ActiveWindow();
            Inspector inspector = application.ActiveInspector();
            if (inspector != null && windowType is Inspector)
            {
                return inspector.CurrentItem as MailItem;
            }
            else
            {
                if (application.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Count > 0)
                {
                   return application.ActiveExplorer().ActiveInlineResponse as MailItem;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            logEx_.Log("Null outlook aplication.", EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

This is how I use the mailitem. (I didint post all the processing but basically I add attachments in the mailitem, recipients, modify the body)

```
string officeEmail = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("foo") ? "foo1" : "foo";
Recipient recipient = mailitem.Recipients.Add(officeEmail);
```

Comment: Which particular OOM method or property gets slower?

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko is not a particular one, everywere  I use the mailitem object the operation is slow.

Comment: Is that online or a cached profile?

Comment: Is Online. I checked now and the Use Cached Exchange mode is disabled

Comment: Do you see any difference if you enable the cached mode?

Comment: I can't enable it is disabled by system administrators. But I can ask to get access and have a look.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I have enabled the cached mode and did some testes. The problem still persists.

Comment: I don't know, sorry.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko forgot to ask if would be a Online mode problem can I do anything to improove the speed? Or is internet speed related?

Comment: Made a test and for each action in Inspector mailtem is around 1-2 ms and from Explorer 1-2 seconds. Drives me crazy!

Comment: You really need to post the relevant snippets of your code for both test cases; impossible to give any kind of advise without seeing the actual code.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I edit the question

Comment: Hmmm.. That looks fine to me. I can only speculate that Inspector caches the mail item, but inline response does not.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko can you please be more specific? How can I check that? If I'm not going to implement this task because is so slow IL have to give an explication.

Comment: You can't check that - that is just what I suspect happens. No way to check unless you have access to Outlook source code and can step through it. Can you be a bit more quantitative? Have you tried to time how long the OOM calls take for the explorer vs inspector MailItem object?

Comment: Yes I tried. The difference is for about 1-2 seconds for each operation. Where Inspector takes 10ms, the Explorer takes 1-2s. Per total when I process something with Inspector the entire operation taks 4-5 sec and with explorer around 15-20 sec.

Comment: Also when using Explorer the processor jumps to 100% and outlook is not responding for short periods of time.